# Как реализовать расчет определенных индикаторов торговли в реальном времени?

Tags: python, asyncio, binance

К примеру, есть функция, которая прослушивает вебсокет binance и обрабатывает ивент, который содержит данные о свечах

```
async def kline_listener(bsm: BinanceSocketManager, client: AsyncClient, symbol: str):
    async with bsm.kline_futures_socket(symbol=symbol, interval=AsyncClient.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE) as stream:
        klines = await client.get_historical_klines(
            symbol,
            AsyncClient.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE,
            "15 minute ago UTC",
            klines_type=HistoricalKlinesType.FUTURES
        )
        klines = form_kline_from_array(klines)
        while True:
            response = await stream.recv()
            kline = Kline(**response["k"])

            length = len(klines)
            if kline.is_closed:
                if length == 15:
                    klines.pop(0)
                klines.append(kline)
            else:
                if length == 14:
                    klines.append(kline)
                    yield calculate_natr(klines)
                elif length == 15:
                    klines.pop()
                    klines.append(kline)
                    yield calculate_natr(klines)
```

Также binance api позволяет получить абсолютно все тикеры, которые доступны на бирже. Необходимо написать условно цикл, в котором надо пройтись по всем тикерам (на данный момент 2260 штук) и создать asyncio таск на функцию get_natr для каждого тикера, чтобы они работали в фоне и для начала выводили (в данном случае индикатор NATR) в консоль

```
async def get_natr(symbol: str, bsm: BinanceSocketManager, client: AsyncClient):
    async for natr in kline_listener(bsm, client, symbol):
        logger.info(f"NATR ({symbol}): {natr}")
```

Comment: @vitidev, я не подразумевал того, чтобы вы запускали код и что то проверяли, согласен, не совсем правильно задал вопрос. Неважно, какие расчеты там производятся, есть функция kline_listener, которая бесконечно выкидывает какие либо данные. У меня есть 2260 "тикеров", которые передаются в функцию get_natr и я бы хотел, чтобы для каждого тикера был запущен этот бесконечный цикл. Как я понял из вашего ответа, это невозможно?

Comment: Тогда я ошибся в трактовке вашего вопроса. Почему невозможно, все возможно. Просто ваш вопрос не очень легко понять. Что есть тикеры? symbol что ли? Может у вас задача вида "хочу следить за всеми изменениями всех монет на бирже в реальном времени, постоянно высчитывать какие то индикаторы и давать сигналу боту на работу", а может и нет (потому что в коде подпись на конкретный symbol)

Comment: @vitidev, да, верно, хочу следить за всеми монетами на бирже и просчитывать некоторые индикаторы, хранить эти данные к примеру в redis или mongodb и формировать топ пар по индикаторам. Тикер - это symbol (напр. BTCUSDT - пара BTC к USDT). Никаких торговых ботов, просто собирать информацию, делать расчеты и составлять динамический топ 10 например

Comment: Ну код выглядит так, как будто поверх get_natr просто сделать `for symbol in symbos: asyncio.ensure_future(get_natr(symbol, ...))`, но это сильно очевидный ответ, да и вряд ли бинанс позволит столько подписок на 1 вебсокет